# Using javascript to rename multiple HTML files using the <TITLE></TITLE> in each file

Tags: javascript, html

I have used HTTRACK to download Federal regulations from a government website, and the resulting HTML files are not intuitively named.  Each file has a `<TITLE></TITLE>` tag set, that would serve nicely to name each file in a fashion that will lend itself to ebook creation.  I want to turn these regulations into an ebook for my Kindle, so that I can have the regulations readily available for reference, rather than having to carry volumes of books with me everywhere.

My preferred text/hex editor, UltraEdit Professional 15.20.0.1026, has scripting commands enable through embedding of the JavaScript engine.  In researching possible solutions to my problem, I found [xmlTitleSave](http://www.ultraedit.com/files/scripts/xmlTitleSave.js) on the IDM UltraEdit website.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Script Name: xmlTitleSave.js
// Creation Date: 2008-06-09
// Last Modified: 
// Copyright: none
// Purpose: find the <title> value in an XML document, then saves the file as the 
// title.xml in a user-specified directory
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Some variables we need
var regex = "<title>(.*)</title>" //Perl regular expression to find title string
var file_path = UltraEdit.getString("Path to save file at? !! MUST PRE EXIST !!",1);

// Start at the beginning of the file
UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();

UltraEdit.activeDocument.unicodeToASCII();

// Turn on regular expressions
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp = true;

// Find it
UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.find(regex);

// Load it into a selection
var titl = UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection;

// Javascript function 'match' will match the regex within the javascript engine 
// so we can extract the actual title via array
t = titl.match(regex);

// 't' is an array of the match from 'titl' based on the var 'regex'
// the 2nd value of the array gives us what we need... then append '.xml'
saveTitle = t[1]+".xml";

UltraEdit.saveAs(file_path + saveTitle);

// Uncomment for debugging
// UltraEdit.outputWindow.write("titl = " + titl);
// UltraEdit.outputWindow.write("t = " + t);
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Can this JavaScript be modified to extract the `<TITLE></TITLE>` contents from an HTML file and rename the files?
2. If the JavaScript cannot be modified easily, is there a script/program/black magic/animal sacrifice that can accomplish the same thing?

EDIT:
I have been able to get the script to work as desired by removing the `UltraEdit.activeDocument.unicodeToASCII();` line and changing the file extension to `.html`.  My only issue now is that while this script works on single open files, it does not batch process the directory.

Comment: in short you have a list of urls and you want a list of the contents of their title tags?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @generalhenry:  I have a directory of files that I need to have renamed.  I would prefer to use the TITLE contects as the file name.

Comment: @coreyward:  I am running Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work out of the box?

I don't know anything about UltraEdit, but as far as a regex engine is concerned, if it can parse `<title>(.*)</title>` out of an XML document, it can do the exact same for HTML.

Just modify the final file title to `.html` instead of `.xml`

```
saveTitle = t[1]+".html";
```

Assuming you can get that script to work as it's intended (point being I don't know UltraEdit), I'm pretty confident that same process will work for HTML.

Comment: I tried the suggestion you provided, however, the result is a garbaged HTML file that is saved with the name `xmlnull.html`.

Comment: I'd recommend uncommenting the debug lines to find out what `t` is. The script comments say `[1]` is the index we're interested in, but for the HTML it could be a separate one, assuming it's a list of regex matches. Also, the "garbaged" html file sounds like a separate issue... perhaps this `UltraEdit.unicodeToASCII()` is doing some funky conversions?

Comment: *smacks forehead*  I totally overlooked that `unicodeToASCII` command.

Comment: Removing the `UltraEdit.unicodeToASCII()` line resolved the garbage issue, and allowed the script to work.  Now to see about modifying it to batch rename!

Comment: Hey, awesome! Now I specifically have 0 idea about how batching stuff works in UltraEdit

Comment: I will continue to work with the script, and will post my final results here when I have a working batch rename.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just about any "scriptable" language to do something like this pretty quickly. Ruby is my favorite:

```
require 'fileutils'

dir = "/your/directory"
files = Dir["#{dir}/*.html"]

files.each do |file|
  html = IO.read file
  title = $1 if html.match /<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/i
  FileUtils.mv file "#{dir}/#{title}.html"
  puts "Renamed #{file} to #{title}.html."
end
```

Obviously if your UltraEdit script worked for you this might be obtuse, but for anybody running a different env, hopefully this is useful.

Comment: "This answer is useful" ... doing a Perl version would be easy too.  @jsutyla - The advantage of an external script is that you don't have to actually load any of the files into the editor; you can batch convert a whole directory full of files with a single command at the command line.

Comment: I saved your code as `rename.rb`, however, when I installed Ruby and tried to run it, I got the following output:  rename.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `file' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
        from rename.rb:6:in `each'
        from rename.rb:6:in `<main>'

Comment: You might need to update it to work with Windows-style path separators (backslashes, rather than the standard forward-slashes).

Comment: @Stephen P:  I'm not well-versed in perl. Do you have any example scripts that you can recommend for this?

Answer (score 1):

XML and HTML are both plain text, and that script is simply running a regular expression on the text to extract the title tags, which are the same in both; the only thing you need to do is change this line:

```
saveTitle = t[1]+".xml";
```

to this:

```
saveTitle = t[1]+".html";
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and trial and error on the scripting side, I ran across a fantastic program for Windows that will do the renaming via TITLE tags:  Flexible Renamer 8.3.  The author's website is http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/, and it manages to handle every bit of what I needed.  Many thanks to @coreyward and @Yuji for their fantastic advice on the scripting end of things.